# Neither setInterval nor setTimeout works react-native ES6

Tags: r, javascript, react-native

I'm trying to get a basic timer going in react-native, but it's not working. I get no errors in the console. It just simply ignores the `setInterval`. I read the [TimerMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html) issue with ES6 (not supported). So what is the alternative if you want to use just a basic `setInterval` timer?, as it simply does not work in its simplest form shown here...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
      console.log('COMPONENTDIDMOUNT')
   //this.timer=     <--//This doesn't work either 
     var timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('I do not leak!');
    }, 5000);
  }
componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('COMPONENTWILLUNMOUNT')
  clearInterval(timer); 
}
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: So do you see anything in the console?

Comment: Your link expressly says they implement the browser timers, so something else is going on here. My guess is this isn't even compiling because you have  a  `ReferenceError`: `timer` in `componentWillUnmount` is not defined.

Comment: you do understand that the timer var is only available in the componentDidMount function - you need to create a var accessible to both functions it is used in - however, your problem seems to suggest that setInterval is never even executed, is that right?

Comment: @Jack @Jaromanda X @zerkms I do not see "I do not leak" in the console. I am not getting any errors, and it does compile. everything else executes fine. I see "COMPONENTDIDMOUNT" in the console, so it's just the `setInterval` which seems to be failing somewhere

Comment: @Jaromanda X I understand the `timer` scope. I will use  `this.timer = this.timer(bind).this; this.timer=setInterval...`.. once I could get past just getting this timer to work.

Comment: `I will use this.timer = this.timer(bind).this;` ... why? that makes no sense

Comment: @Jaromanda X Regardless, that's not the issue here. The issue is `setInterval` not working.

Comment: I understand, but I was commenting about the comment in the code, and did point out that I suspected the problem was that your setInterval callback wasn't working

Comment: @cube So to be clear, you've tried this with the clearly problematic `componentWillUnmount` removed too, correct?

Comment: The call back goes straight to `console.log`, it should work right out of the box the way it is.

Comment: @Jack Yes that's correct

Comment: let me get this straight - you get `COMPONENTDIDMOUNT` and `COMPONENTWILLUNMOUNT` on the console, but you never get `I do not leak!` on the console - even if there's more than 5 seconds between the first two?

Comment: @ Jaromanda X That's correct

Comment: I've cut down your code to the bare minimum, and it works fine (once you use this.timer in BOTH places)

Comment: I added pics to this post. Pic of my console and my code

Comment: @ Jaromanda X You compiled and ran in emulator? and it works?

Comment: Ok got it working. It had to do with the TIME DRIFT issue with the debugger and the emulator. `adb shell "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"` resolved the issue.

Comment: @Jaromanda X Thanks for confirming the code works.

Comment: compiled? emulator? this is javascript, nothing that complex

Comment: @Jaromanda X Ok, you've confused me now, do you even know what react-native is? compiled build emulator is part of it all. Never mind tho, I got it working. Thanks!

Comment: Javascript is javascript

Answer (score 33):

You need to save the time as an instance variable and clear it on component unmount. Example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._interval = setInterval(() => {
    // Your code
  }, 5000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this._interval);
}
```

Comment: For those using react-navigation componentWillUnmount() is not called. How to clearInterval in that case?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal , you could use Navigation events blur which will be called whenever a screen goes out of focus.

Comment: Can you share any code snippet or any url for the sample code how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this module as Timers in react-native is little pain with ES6.
https://github.com/fractaltech/react-native-timer

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot, it clearly mentions there is a time difference between your device and debugger. Please sync both devices to use a time server (automatically set date and time) and issue will be resolved.

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9436